# display modified date and time of all files from a directory in php

Tags: php, html-table, filemtime

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I want to display modified date and time of all files from a directory(outgoing_folder).

```
$destination = 'outgoing_folder';  
$mp3_files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($destination)); /* Line#Z */
print_r($mp3_files);  /* Line#X */
```

*Line#X* print the following:

```
Array ([2] => 36017P.mp3 [3] => 36031P.mp3 [4] => hello.mp3)
```

I have used *Line#Z*  at *Line#A* and *Line#B* in order to display the modified date and time of all files from the directory.

```
<?php   foreach ($mp3_files as $file ) :  ?>  /* Line #A */
<tr>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file, ".mp3"); ?></td>
   <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("F d Y",filemtime("$file")); ?></td>   /* Line #B */
</tr>
<?php
   endforeach;
?>
```

*Line#B* display the following o/p (which is not the modified date and time of files):

```
Date 
December 31 1969
December 31 1969
December 31 1969
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code at *Line#B* so that I am able to retrieve modified date and time of all the files in a directory.

Comment: Directory path maybe? `<?php echo date("F d Y",filemtime("outgoing_folder/$file")); ?>`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Although, it worked. I am wondering why did you use `outgoing_folder/` ?  As Line#Z has already `outgoing_folder`.

Comment: No your array `Array ([2] => 36017P.mp3 [3] => 36031P.mp3 [4] => hello.mp3)` has only the filnames not the directory so how does `filemtime` know where they are?  If you use `glob` instead of `scandir` it will save the path in the array.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It worked thanks !